# Google fonts — partial rendering in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I use Google Open Sans font (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) with cyrillic. And if I have stressed word (  ́  — accent symbol is missing in font-set), Google Chrome renders only the part after accent. But another browsers haven't same problem.

Rendering comparison:
[image: Comparative Google and Edge rendering]
I understand that every browser has own render-engine, but I very want to solve or avoid this trouble. What should I do?

```css
.open-sans-font {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="open-sans-font">
 <p> філігра́нний — несамови́тий </p>
 <p> філігранний — несамовитий </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, both screenshots show what looks like the same thing, save for the first ф in Chrome. Can you further clarify what you need us to notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added ***“text=...чшщьюя́”*** to my Google Web Fonts API request.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700&text=АБВГҐДЕЄЖЗИІЇЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЮЯабвгґдеєжзиіїйклмнопрстуфхцчшщьюя́" rel="stylesheet">
```

It turns out that the accent symbol belonged to **latin-ext** charset

Answer (score 0):

Taking it as you want to make sure the width is the same for that line. I would ass a class to that `<p>` for example

```
<p class="RenderTrouble">філігра́нний — несамови́тий</p>
```

And in your css put

```
.RenderTrouble {
              max-width: 200px; /* Or how ever many pixels it is long */
}
```

And that should do it. the only problem is finding how many pixels long the edge render is.
I'll do the math;
1398 -19 = 1379
The length of the sentence is 1379px so make the css

```
.RenderTrouble {
              max-width: 1379px; /* Or how ever many pixels it is long */
}
```

Well in theory anyway. it isn't working for me so I'm afraid you're out of luck. I will keep trying to see if I can get it
I give up [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97ESs.png)

```
<img src="./Untitled.png" style="max-width: 210px; height: 120;">
```

Comment: @PsyhoWolf, It's good idea. But, unfortunately, creating image on each sentence is too costly.